# Rails 4 - Rendering partial with access to class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, partial

I have two classes Bid (`has_many :mozs`) and Moz (`belongs_to :bid`). I am trying to render a partial for creating Moz objects.

```
<%= f.fields_for :mozs do |builder| %>
  <%= render "moz_fields", :f => builder %>
<% end %>
```

in my partial:

```
<div class="field fields">
 <%= f.label :url, "Comparative URL" %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :url %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :destroy %>
 <%= link_to_function "remove", "remove_fields(this)"%>
</div>
```

When the contents of the partial are in the `fields_for` tag:

```
<%= f.fields_for :mozs do |builder| %>
 <div class="field fields">
  <%= builder.label :url, "Comparative URL" %><br>
  <%= builder.text_field :url %>
  <%= builder.hidden_field :destroy %>
  <%= link_to_function "remove", "remove_fields(this)"%>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

then everything works fine. But I need it in a partial to dynamically add the fields. When I keep it in a partial I get this error: `` undefined method `url' for NilClass:Class ``.

I don't understand why the class would be nil just because I put it in a partial.

Comment: Shouldn't you be accessing `f.label :url` instead of `builder.label :url`?  Since you're passing `builder` into the partial as `f` when you `render "moz_fields", :f => builder`?

Comment: @HeliosdeGuerra I am doing exactly as you said. The last block of code, where builder is used, is what works when I don't render a partial. All that code would be in the fields_for tag. I'll edit that so it is more apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem will likely be with your rendering of a partial inside the `fields_for` tag && you're not using [the locals argument](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables):

```
<%= render partial: "moz_fields", locals: { f: builder } %>

#moz_fields
<%= f.fields_for :mozs do |b| %>
    <div class="field fields">
        <%= b.label :url, "Comparative URL" %><br>
        <%= b.text_field :url %>
        <%= b.hidden_field :destroy %>
        <%= link_to_function "remove", "remove_fields(this)"%>
    </div>
<% end %>
```